# How to insert SQLite more than 2 rows?

Tags: android, sqlite

So I created this DB.

```
    private static final String NOME_DB = "bancomuseu.db";

    public static final String TABELA = "tbl_itens";


    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String TITULO = "titulo";
    public static final String DESCRICAO = "descricao";
    public static final String INFORMACOES = "informacoes";
    public static final String MAISINFO = "maisinfo";
    public static final int VERSAO = 18;


     DbHelper (Context context) {
         super(context, NOME_DB, null, VERSAO);
     }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String sql = "CREATE TABLE "+TABELA+" (" +
                ID + " integer primary key, " +
                TITULO + " text, " +
                DESCRICAO + " text, " +
                INFORMACOES + " text, " +
                MAISINFO + " text " +
                ")";

        db.execSQL(sql);
```

Now I want to insert rows into this table

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO `tbl_itens` (`id`,`titulo`, `descricao`, `INFORMACOES`, `maisinfo`) VALUES ('1', 'Titulo1', 'Descricao1', 'Informacoes1', 'maisinfo1') +

"INSERT INTO `tbl_itens` (`id`,`titulo`, `descricao`, `INFORMACOES`, `maisinfo`) VALUES ('2', 'Titulo2', 'Descricao3', 'Informacoes4', 'maisinfo5');";

db.execSQL(insert);
```

What is the correct way to insert more than 1 row at the time?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO 'tablename' ('column1', 'column2') VALUES
  ('data1', 'data2'),
  ('data1', 'data2'),
  ('data1', 'data2'),
  ('data1', 'data2');
```